# Dynamically get records between two dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a project at the moment where I have a voting system and on the index page for the vote model I can see the average vote for the last week. However I'd like to be able to have the user be able to choose the date between which the rating is averaged. I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

Currently I have a view which shows @average which is defined as:

```
Vote.where(date: (Date.today - 7)..(Date.today)).average(:score)
```

My initial though was to include a 'date range' attribute to the model and then have the average calculated from those dates, which is set by a form in the index view, but that seems like a lot of overhead for such a simple task.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of model attribute, you could write a class method in the model, that accepts start_date and end_date as arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the help, so if I create that method, how can I then allow the user to submit their own values for start_date and end_date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wanted to achieve this from the model point of view,
You can use the dynamic scope of rails to achieve this,

In your model,

**Method1:**

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
   scope :average_score, ->(date1,date2) { where(date: (date1)..(date2) )}  
end
```

Now, on your controller or the view , you can call something like,

**`@average = Vote.average_score(Date.today - 7 , Date.today).average(:id)`**

**Method 2:**

You can take a method and call the scope from the method.

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
       scope :average_score, ->(date1,date2) { where(date: (date1)..(date2) )}  

       def self.average_score_value(d1, d2)
        self.average_score(d1,d2).average(:id)
       end
 end
```

Now, on your controller or the view , you can call something like,

**`@average = Vote.average_score_value(Date.today - 7 , Date.today)`**

Here is an **example with user table**, I have taken `created_at` column

```
2.3.1 :036 > User.average_score(Date.today - 7,Date.today).average(:id)

 (0.5ms)  SELECT AVG(`users`.`id`) FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`created_at` BETWEEN '2016-10-19' AND '2016-10-26')
 => nil
```

The scope is,

`scope :average_score, ->(date1,date2) { where(created_at: (date1)..(date2) )}`

[Here is the reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: @user2320239, please check this answer. you can achieve in model itself

Comment: Thanks for the help, so if I create that method, how can I then allow the user to submit their own values for start_date and end_date and then have the page update?

Comment: I'm also not tied to doing this in the model, if it can be done another way that is easier I'm fine with that.

Comment: Good answer. We could also do the average in the model just to keep it all in one place... `def self.average_score_value(d1, d2); self.average_score(d1,d2).average(:id); end` then OP can do `@average = User.average_score_value(from_date, to_date)`

Comment: you can just give two drop downs and a button, then on the button click, you can just call this scope from controller.

Comment: send the two values from the drop down to the controller, call the method given by me, and then show the same in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `form_tag` and a couple of `date_field_tag`s (say `start_date` and `end_date`) and a submit button on the index page itself, perhaps at the top.  When the user submits you can use the inputted parameters, and re-render the index.

```
@average = Vote.where(date: (params[:start_date].to_date)..(params[:end_date].to_date)).average(:score)
render :index
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a simple form on the `index` page

```
<%= form_tag '/index' do %>
  <%= date_field_tag :start_date %>
  <%= date_field_tag :end_date %>
  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

add a route to your routes.rb

```
post '/index', to 'users#average'
```

add a method to UsersController

```
  def average
    @average = Vote.where(date: (params[:start_date].to_date)..(params[:end_date].to_date)).average(:score)
    render :index
  end
```